# How do I get my "Swing" button in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, swing

While following a youtube tutorial, I noticed my program didn't have a "Design" or "Source" panel, even worse I can't find a Swing button. Do I need to download something...?
[scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1fVK.png)

Comment: *"Do I need to download something...?"* Yes, this: [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html). If you can't find a download link for it, go through it online. Code made in GUI designer is not portable between IDEs, and when that doesn't matter, the resulting code will be much more robust if the programmer understands how to code GUIs by writing them in Java.

Comment: Is [WindowBuilder](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/windowbuilder) installed? If yes, make sure to open/create the GUI class with the right editor/dialog.

Comment: howlger's comment is sufficient for Eclipse. On a separate note, you can also use Netbeans 8.1 which does not need additional plugins. Simply add a new JFrame file in the project and the IDE will automatically open a **Design** window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you howlger, the solution is simple, follow this link :
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/windowbuilder
By simply downloading it via browser or dragging a link to the Eclipse workspace and following the instructions.